# Detect if page was access from google result or not direct from my domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to detect if the user landed on my page through a google result, or to be more correct if the page was not accessed with in a link on my page. The codesample below is a example of what im trying to do

```
bool googleResult = "somecode";

if (googleResult){
     //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `Request.UrlReferrer`.

Comment: Do be aware that the client can set referrer to whatever they want. It cannot be relied on for security.

Comment: so `Request.UrlReferrer != "mydomain"`?

Comment: @Dejan.S: `UrlReferrer` is a `Uri` object.  Look at its properties.